# How to center the image jpg in the preview window?

Tags: c#, winforms

When printing jpg images have the problem.

> When displayed in the preview window the image is not centered.
>   How to center the image jpg in the preview window?

```
private void PrintJPG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    photo = Image.FromFile(@"C:\...\Рисунок.jpg");

    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
    PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    dlg.Height = 1000;
    dlg.Width = 1000;
    dlg.Document = printDoc;

    dlg.ShowDialog();
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;

    Graphics gg = Graphics.FromImage(photo);

    RectangleF marginBounds = e.MarginBounds;
    if (!printDocument1.PrintController.IsPreview)
        marginBounds.Offset(-e.PageSettings.HardMarginX, -e.PageSettings.HardMarginY);

    float x = marginBounds.X / 100f + (marginBounds.Width / 100f - (float)photo.Width / gg.DpiX) / 2f;
    float y = marginBounds.Y / 100f + (marginBounds.Height / 100f - (float)photo.Height / gg.DpiY) / 2f;

    g.DrawImage(photo, x, y);

    //Don't call g.Dispose(). Operating System will do this job.
    gg.Dispose();//You should call it to release graphics object immediately.
}
```

Comment: have you tryed to implement your image drawing, like discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499860/graphics-drawstring-center-in-printdocument-width)?

Comment: Please be more precise. Are you having problems centering the image in the printed page? Or are you having problem centering the print preview itself? Either way, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, and a precise, detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.